# What is causing this for loop to behave strangely?

Tags: python, for-loop, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to build a Caesar cipher. Below is a small portion of the decoding portion of the code. Essentially, it takes an input and shifts it (key) spaces to the left in the alphabet.

For some reason, it's returning the answer out of order - 'uulz' instead of 'zulu'. Why is the for loop iterating out of order in this case?

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

working = ['e','z','q','z']

key = 5

for position in working:
    working[working.index(position)] = alphabet[alphabet.index(position)-key]

print(working)
```

Comment: Which language are you using?  It looks like Python, so I've added that tag.  It is almost always beneficial to add the tag for the primary language of your question.  If this is from the CS50 course, it might be worth adding a [tag:cs50] tag too.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Yep, it's Python, and it's from a different course called '100 days of code' on Udemy.

Comment: After the first substitution, the string becomes `zzqz`, so on the next iteration `working.index(position)` returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the same list that you are looping through. Try assigning a new list for the results.

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
working = ['e','z','q','z']
key = 5
new_list=[]
for position in working:
    new_list.append(alphabet[alphabet.index(position)-key])

print(new_list)
['z', 'u', 'l', 'u']
```

or alternatively, try:

```
for num, position in enumerate(working):
    working[num] = alphabet[alphabet.index(position)-key]
print(working)
```